# Keeping properties secure within mapbox-gl

Tags: geojson, security, mapbox-gl-js

Simply put, how could one develop a mapbox-gl application where the properties are secured ?

For example, take a look at this simple mapbox-gl map with properties:

http://jsbin.com/hovawa/edit?html,js,console,output

In the code I have property called "secretproperty" with value "abc123".

Is it possible to somehow hide/encode this if someone attempted to read the property info in the browser's debug mode?
What would be the best approach?

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to hide a particular property is to encrypt or obfuscate the entire javascript source. See this [stack overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-protect-javascript)

Comment: Perhaps you could add a bit more about what you are trying to achieve. There may be another way, such as moving the property you want to protect server-side.

Comment: Sorry for the late response... But am trying to pull locations/properties from ajax/dbase calls  (in json format) and load them into the mapbox-gl.   Would like to somehow protect the data - prevent prying eyes looking at the data via the browser debug.  Obfuscation seems like best approach, thanks!  But if there's anything else I'm all ears...